# strtotime("-5 hours") not working?

Tags: php, strtotime

I thought strtotime() would convert a "string" into a timestamp. If I add on to the time, it works fine, but if I try to subtract, it doesn't. Does anyone know a workaround?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not specific to PHP5, please tag correctly. http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php

Comment: How doesn't it work? `var_dump(strtotime("-5 hours"))` outputs a proper, non-false, value for me.

Comment: have you tried "-05:00" to let it know its hours instead of "hours"

Comment: Those “smartquotes” round the string might mess things up. Are you sure you have copied and pasted exactly what it says in your code? Could you have typed some special character that *looks* like a minus sign but actually isn't one?

Comment: @DevelopingChris - Not necessary, `strtotime` can parse "hours".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend reading Derick Rethans's excellent guide on Date and Time, http://derickrethans.nl/talks/time-zendcon9.pdf, explanatory slides start at slide 16.

He's the author of PHP's date and time functions and recommends that you use the DateTime classes if possible.

Answer (score 3):

It seems to work fine for me...

```
echo strtotime("-5 hours");
```

Result:

```
1282061972
```

Comment: Ditto. (You beat me to it...)